# Custom taxonomy rewrite with query var returns %2F in URL

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I'm facing a (hopefully) small issue right now I can't seem to solve.

First of all my page is set up in a way that all my projects (custom post type) are displayed on one big page with a query var filter containing my custom taxonomies.

So the URL with all the projects is `example.com/projects/` and the filter turns the URL into this `example.com/projects/?TAXONOMY=XYZ`.

What I have done is list the custom taxonomies and their values on the single-projects.php page and all I'm trying to do is to **rewrite the taxonomy links to lead directly to the project query and not to the taxonomy archive**.

Another example, because I can't properly put my problem into words.
Right now the taxonomy link leads to this: `example.com/projects/TAXONOMY/XYZ/` but I want the link to be `example.com/projects/?TAXONOMY=XYZ`.

I have tried using the rewrite function while registering my custom taxonomy
`'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'projects/?TAXONOMY=' )`
but this returns the following URL:
`example.com/projects/?TAXONOMY=/xyz/` which turns into `example.com/projects/?TAXONOMY=%2Fxyz%2F` once the page is loaded.

This already works and displays the right posts but it looks incredibly ugly.
Is there a way to make the taxonomy link look like this `example.com/projects/?TAXONOMY=XYZ` and not like this `example.com/projects/?TAXONOMY=/xyz/` ?